# Skill checks for Magic Item Creation

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, skills, crafting

Let us say I want to create a [Ring of Sustenance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-sustenance). The DC is 5 + CL (in this case 5). Since I am a Wizard and do not know the spell '[Create food and water](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-food-and-water)' and want to do it in half the time I put +10 on top. So the DC is 20.

The [rules for item creation](https://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html) say

> At the end of this process, the spellcaster must make a single skill
>   check (usually Spellcraft, but sometimes another skill) to finish the
>   item. If an item type has multiple possible skills, you choose which
>   skill to make the check with.

Looking at the Creating Ring part I find

> Skill Used in Creation: Spellcraft or Craft (jewelry).

and finally there is another rule that has to be applied

> Item Requires Skill to Use: Some items require a specific skill to get
>   them to function. This factor should reduce the cost about 10%.

After spending money and time I choose Spellcraft (since I do not have Craft(jewelry)) and roll a 22.

I have created the ring but does the last rule for getting a 10% discount also apply or do I have to do another skill check? If so, when do I have to make the skill check and can that be a Spellcraft check as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That last rule is only for magic items that requires a particular skill to be able to *use* it, and as such has nothing to do with the skills needed, or used, to create them.

Say you crate a "Ring of the Thief", which requires 5 ranks in Stealth in order to be operational. Then, and only then, would the cost of creating this ring be decreased by 10%. A Ring of Sustenance that can be used by anyone does not fall into this category.

Answer (score 1):

The 10 % discount applies when creating and designing a new magic item that requires ranks in a particular skill or ability to use.

> Many factors must be considered when determining the price of **new** magic items.

That is, if you were to create a Ring of sustenance that only sustains (say) jewelers, then it would be cheaper.